# Finding the most popular articles based on user "likes" and "dislikes"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Users can add articles that other users can "like" or "dislike".

I need to find the most popular articles, calculated as likes minus dislikes. For example, if an article has 3 likes and 1 dislike it should be given a popularity value of 2.

This is my database structure and I join them together:

My articles table:

```
id | user_id | title | description | views | created_at | updated_at
```

My likes table:

```
id | user_id | article_id | like_type | created_at | updated_at
```

How can I find the most popular articles?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how you'd write it with a normal MySQL query?

Comment: Like type is boolean? what is it?

Comment: @RossWilson no i don't

Comment: For a question like this to be answerable, you need to furnish some example rows for each table, and an example of the results you need. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you asked for with a simple group by and order statement, something like that should work:

```
return Article::select('title', DB::Raw('SUM(2*likes.like_type-1) as likes_count'))
    ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
    ->groupBy('articles.id')
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

I assumed that like_type is a boolean stating 0 for dislike or 1 for like - if not, you will need to change the SUM statement.

Comment: yessss its working :D 
but can you explain it to me
what is  raw and group by

Comment: i don't understand this
DB::Raw('SUM( 2 * likes.like -1))

Comment: Raw - let's you write **raw** sql inside your laravel query building. `2*likes.like-1` is my way of turning [0,1] -> [-1,1], so when summing like will add one and dislike will subtracts one.

Comment: can you help me in the question too 
it's for order now 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265415/laravel-table-structure-showing-the-most-liked-articles-and-less-views