# laravel table structure showing the most liked articles and less views

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

users can add articles and other users can like or dislike I need most liked with the less view

example : 
article (A) has 500 views and 10 like - article (B) has 50 views and 10 likes
 the order will be (B) than (A)

This is my database structure and I join them together:

articles table:

```
id | user_id | title | description | views | created_at | updated_at
```

likes table:

```
id | user_id | article_id | like_type | created_at | updated_at
```

query to get likes count :

```
Article::leftJoin('likes', 'likes.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
        ->select('articles.*', DB::Raw('SUM( 2 * likes.like_type -1) as likes_count'))
        ->groupBy('articles.
        ->get();
```

how can i order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by multiple columns in laravel by chaining orderBy.

In your case for example you will want to first order by "likes_count" descending (=biggest first) and then by views ascending (= smallest first, this is the default value).

So you will do:

```
return Article::select('title', DB::Raw('SUM(2*likes.like_type-1) as likes_count'))
    ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
    ->groupBy('articles.id')
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'DESC')->orderBy('views')
    ->get();
```

Comment: i try it if article (A) has 500 views and 11 like - article (B) has 50 views and 10 likes 
it get A cuz A more likes 
its wrong i need B here cuz A has 2% likes and b has 20% likes

Comment: This is not what you described in your question... You can't have it both ways: have the biggest likes first, and the case you described here. You can try and create some kind of formula for the order instead of number of likes then do something like `SUM(2*likes.like_type-1+articles.view/10)` and play with it.